# sql place in a column the value that is true

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, filtering

Hi im filtering a table a have 3 fields for the phone number `number1, number2, number3` from the table clients so im filtering the name of the client and i want to place in a new row only the field that applies to a certain condition

Example:

```
  select name from clients where len(number1) =10 or len(number2) = 10 or len(number3)=10
```

the result i want its

```
name  row
jhon  1234567890
```

(the one of the 3 row that the length is = 10)

Comment: Please tag RDBMS you are using, also please add actual data for querying

Comment: Have you tried using a CASE?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Comment: `coalesce(num1, num2, num3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I choosed **case** as a solution:

```
Select name ,
Case when Len(number1) = 10 then number1 
else when Len(number2) = 10 then number2 
else number3 end as [row]
From clients
Where len(number1) =10 
or len(number2) = 10 
or len(number3) = 10
```

Comment: This answer could be much improved by providing some explanation of the code and better formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `CASE`

```
select NAME, CASE 
WHEN LEN(NUM1)=10 THEN
NUM1
WHEN LEN(NUM2)=10 THEN
NUM2
WHEN LEN(NUM3)=10 THEN
NUM3
END ROW
FROM clients;
```

If you only wanted to have rows where either `num1` or `num2` or `num3` any of them has value length 10. Then, you need to add `WHERE` clause else that's not required.

Alternatively, you can also make use of `coalesce`, but that will give you unexpected output, if columns values are not null.

**[>>Demo<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48a7e/2)**

Comment: You missed the filtering part the user asked for and shown clearly in his example , also you used different column names !